# Queue runner must be configured before execution. When trying to upgrade in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, upgrade

What is the logic behind that? I can't upgrade, I am just not familiar enough with this codebase... Why is there no queueuRunner in the session

```
public static function instance($qrid) {
    if (!empty($_SESSION['queueRunners'][$qrid])) {
      return unserialize($_SESSION['queueRunners'][$qrid]);
    }
    else {
      return NULL;
    }
  }
```

Does not find queueRunners in the session, returns null... thus the error message in title... When are those queueRunners created?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some docs about queues at https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/queues/ but I don't think that helps you here.

You might try upgrading via command line instead: `cv upgrade:db`. See https://github.com/civicrm/cv if you don't have `cv` installed.